# Can't add libraries to Eclipse Java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I know I've seen the answer somewhere to this question but I just can't seem to find it right now...

I've checked out my Java web application project using SVN in Eclipse Galileo.  I'm trying to figure out how to add libraries to my project but I don't have any options to do so.  Here's a screenshot of what options I have when I display the properties for my project:

[image]

How can I get the ability to add libraries to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that project was not created as a Java project in Eclipse. I haven't used the svn client in Eclipse very much, but when you check out the project, there should be an option to Check Out As... and then make sure it's a Java Project, not just a "general" or "basic" project.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are in Package Explorer perspective. Then `Right click on the project folder ->properties->Java Build Path->Libraries` .

Also make sure the code you checked out from SVN has the eclipse `.project` and `.classpath` files in project ROOT folder otherwise it will not be deemed as a project. In that case do `File->New->SVN-> (select the svn repo)->Check out as a new Java Project`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your project isn't recognized by eclipse as a Java project, try this, create a new Java project and import your java files there.